# Is it possible to overload an operator with a function as a parameter?

Tags: c++, function, class, struct, operator-overloading

I just discovered operator overloading and I am just chuffed to bits with it. In testing its uses, I came across one case that I can't seem to make work, and I cannot find the appropriate resources to resolve.

I am trying to overload an operator which would take a function as an argument. My goal is to create a structure that can execute any function given to it (within reason, like submit commands that would follow the same general structure). Passing a `struct` or `class` would not work in this case because the internal operation of the operator would contain an execute function. If the `struct` or `class` does not have a matching member function, then the operation would not work. Such as in the following case:

```
struct s_test1 {
     void funcA() {}
}
struct s_test2 {
     void funcB() {}
}
struct s_doer {
     friend void operator<<(auto, auto& s_input){
          s_input.funcA(); // would fail for s_test2
          s_input.funcB(); // would fail for s_test1
     }
}
```

Ultimately, I would like to create something like this pseudo-code:

```
void func0(int& storage) { storage = 0; }
void func1(int& storage) { storage = 1; }
void func2(int& storage) { storage = 2; }

void alt_func(int& storage, int alt) { storage = alt; }

struct s_doer {
     friend void operator<<(auto, void(*func)()){
          int storage;
          func(storage);
          cout << storage << endl; // to check if it worked, idk
     }
}

int main() {
    s_doer{} << func0();
    s_doer{} << func1();
    s_doer{} << alt_func(); // alternatively 's_doer << alt_func(), 0' where '0' is the alt parameter of 'alt_func'
}
```

Here is my current implementation attempt:

```
struct s_doer {
    friend void operator<<(auto, void (*func)()) {
        std::cout << "test" << std:endl;
        func();
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    }
};
struct s_informer {
    s_informer(int n) {
        info = n;
    }
    void inform() {
        std::cout << info << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int info;
    friend void operator<<(auto, const void (*func)());
};

s_informer informer(2);

int main() {
    s_doer{} << informer.inform();
}
```

I can't seem to get passed the `no operator "<<" matches these operands` error.

Some of my other attempts have been:

```
friend void operator<<(auto, std::function<void()> func) {...}

template<typename input>
using Func = void(*)(input in);
friend void operator<<(auto, Func func) {...}

typedef void (*Func)(int n);
friend void operator<<(auto, Func func) {...}
```

Is overloading an operator with a functional input possible? Is it possible to specify parameters during overloading for the function as well?

How would it be done?

Comment: `alt_func` takes two parameters, and its unclear what arguments that `operator<<` should pass to that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`informer.inform()` calls the function immediately, while you want to delay the call until `operator<<`.

You can pass a lambda that calls it, then call it in `operator<<`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct s_doer
{
    template <typename F>
    friend void operator<<(s_doer, F &&func)
    {
        std::cout << "test\n";
        std::forward<F>(func)();
        std::cout << "test\n";
    }
};

struct s_informer
{
    s_informer(int n)
    {
        info = n;
    }
    void inform()
    {
        std::cout << info << std::endl;
    }

  private:
    int info;
};

s_informer informer(2);

int main()
{
    s_doer{} << []{informer.inform();};
}
```

Notice that I've changed the second parameter of `operator<<` to be templated, otherwise you won't be able to accept capturing lambdas (which is good for generality, though this specific lambda is not capturing).

I also changed the first parameter from `auto` to `s_doer`. The former, while clever, can have unintended side effects:

```
template <typename> struct A {};

int main()
{
    A<s_doer>{} << []{informer.inform();}; // This actually compiles! But you don't want it to.
}
```

Comment: Why should I avoid doing the `A<s_doer>{} << []{informer.inform();};` implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I'm throwing in an alternative which builds a `std::tuple` of `std::function`s and at the end of the full expression, calls all the collected functions. For functions that requires arguments, you'd pack those in a lambda.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <class T = std::tuple<>>
struct s_doer {
    ~s_doer() {
        // time to die, call the collected functions:
        std::apply([](auto&&... funcs) { ((funcs ? funcs() : void()), ...); }, t);
    }

    T t;

    template <class F>
    friend auto operator<<(s_doer&& d, F&& f) {
        std::function func{std::forward<F>(f)};
        auto tc = std::tuple_cat(std::move(d.t), std::tuple{std::move(func)});
        // return a new s_doer with the collected functions so far
        return s_doer<decltype(tc)>{std::move(tc)};
    }
};
```

```
int main() {
    s_doer{} << [] { std::cout << "Hello\n"; } << [] { std::cout << "fab\n"; };
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
fab
```

---

A more light-weight version without `std::function`s:

```cpp
template <class T = std::tuple<>>
struct s_doer {
    ~s_doer() {
        // time to die, call the collected functions:
        if (last) std::apply([](auto&&... funcs) { (..., funcs()); }, t);
    }

    T t;
    bool last = false;

    template <class F>
    friend auto operator<<(s_doer&& d, F&& f) {
        auto tc = std::tuple_cat(std::move(d.t), std::tuple{std::forward<F>(f)});
        d.last = false;
        // return a new s_doer with the collected functions so far
        return s_doer<decltype(tc)>{std::move(tc), true};
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`alt_func` takes two parameters, and its unclear what arguments that `operator<<` should pass to that function. But if we ignore that, then your first attempt was very close.

`friend void operator<<(auto, void(*func)())` should have been `friend void operator<<(s_doer&&, void(*func)(int&))`. You definitely want to specify as much as is reasonable, which is why you want to use `s_doer&&` on the left.  And the right side takes pointers to functions, and those functions each take an `int&` parameter, and return void, so you have to specify the `int&` parameter.

And then when calling `operator<<`, you don't want to pass the *result* of func0, so you don't want to call it, so you don't want to type `func0()`. Instead, you want to pass the function *itself*: `s_doer{} << func0;`

```
struct s_doer {
     friend void operator<<(s_doer&&, void(*func)(int&)){
          int storage;
          func(storage);
          cout << storage << endl; // to check if it worked, idk
     }
};

int main() {
    s_doer{} << func0;
    s_doer{} << func1;
    //s_doer{} << alt_func; // alternatively 's_doer << alt_func(), 0' where '0' is the alt parameter of 'alt_func'
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e215b7629acf8a76

It almost never makes sense to have a parameter that accepts functions with *any* signature, because there's no way to call it, because you don't know which parameters to pass. and it is therefore useless. But if needed, you could use templates.

```
template<class...Args>
void operator<<(s_doer&&, void(*func)(Args&&...)) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(values)...); 
    //not sure where you plan to get `values` from, but there's ways
}
```

Also note that compilers have a hard time optimizing function pointers, so often we avoid them and allow the function type itself to be a template parameter, which allows functionoid classes instead, like `std::less` and such. These might cause binary bloat, but are also easier to optimize.

Comment: `operator<<` with >2 arguments wouldn't compile.

Comment: What would be the proper convention to call the operator with the arguments?
`s_doer{} << alt_func, 2;`?

Comment: I've removed those extra arguments